# How do I get variables from my main module in Python?

Tags: python, module, pyqt

I am a Structural Engineer by trade and I am trying to automate the creation of 3D models using scripts.

So far I have created three modules; the GUI module using PyQt4, a main module that controls the signals from the GUI, and an export module which "should" pull the variables from main module and generate a script that can be read by my analysis program.

So far the I can't pull the variables from main module when clicking the export  menu in the GUI because variable names are not defined.

If I import the main module into the export module to get the variables, I get errors with the Ui_MainWindow.

I have tried to simplify what I am doing below.

**main.py module**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from export import newFile

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
    super(Main, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)


    self.setName()

    self.ui.actionExport.triggered.connect(self.exportName)

def exportName(self):
    self.exportStaad = newFile().createNewFile()

def setName(self):
    self.ui.tbo_Name.textChanged.connect(self.name_Changed)

def name_Changed(self):
    someName = self.ui.tbo_Name.text()
    print('Name = ' + someName)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Main()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

gui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tbo_Name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.tbo_Name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 150, 20))
        self.tbo_Name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tbo_Name"))
        self.lab_Name = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lab_Name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 40, 20))
        self.lab_Name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lab_Name"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFile"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionExport = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExport.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExport"))
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExport)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.lab_Name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name:", None))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File", None))
        self.actionExport.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

export.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from os import path
import math

class newFile():
    def createNewFile(dest):
        '''
        Creates file
        '''

        name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName ()

        f = open(name, 'w')
        f.write('Hello' + someName)


        f.close
```

Comment: Could you list the exact error? Is that `ImportError`?

Comment: NameError: name 'someName' is not defined

Comment: When I import main.py into export.py.... i get ImportError.

Comment: How are your files arranged on disk?

Comment: It looks like `someName` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The method called createNewFile(dest) inside the class newFile uses undefined var someName at  **f.write('Hello' + someName)**.
This causes the error as it is not defined in the class. Define a variable before you use it.

Comment: The someName variable is defined in main.py  How do I get the variable from main.py to export.py?  I have tried importing main.py but that also causes some problems.

Comment: You are using newFile class of export.py in main.py as self.exportStaad = newFile().createNewFile() but if you see in export.py file, the createNewFile() method needs dest as parameter, which you should provide while calling. The someName from main.py should also be passed as parameter to export.py methods. For example:

def createNewFile(dest, someName) and should be called providing these params. Hope this helps.